protoc generated c# code does not compile
I'm not a Windows/Visual Studio person, so maybe I'm doing something obviously wrong. I'm going to have to write a gRPC wrapper around a library for .NET 4.8. That means I won't be able to use the newer grpc-dotnet and should use the older Grpc.Core library.
As far as I can tell, I need to manually generate the C# code using protoc, so I'm using this command:
protoc --proto_path=. --csharp_out=grpc .\greet.proto --grpc_out=grpc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="C:\users\foo\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\0.5.0\tools\grpc_csharp_plugin.exe"

I get two files Greet.cs and GreetGrpc.cs which I add to my Visual Studio project. I've also added some nuggets I thought are relevant (Google.Protobuf, Grpc.Core, Grpc.Tools, Grpc.Net.Client). The generated code does not compile though.
For example this line:
static readonly Marshaller<global::Greet.HelloRequest> __Marshaller_HelloRequest = Marshallers.Create((arg) => arg.ToByteArray(), global::Greet.HelloRequest.ParseFrom);

would cause an error:

'HelloRequest' does not contain a definition for 'ParseFrom'

Also this line:
static readonly Method<global::Greet.PrepareRequest, global::Greet.PrepareResponse> __Method_Prepare = new Method<global::Greet.PrepareRequest, global::Greet.PrepareResponse>(
    MethodType.Unary,
    "Prepare",
    __Marshaller_PrepareRequest,
    __Marshaller_PrepareResponse);

causes:

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'responseMarshaller' of 'Method<PrepareRequest, PrepareResponse>.Method(MethodType, string, string, Marshaller, Marshaller)'

I would appreciate any help.

".nuget\packages\grpc.tools\0.5.0"! Is that actually the 0.5.0 version of GRPC Tools from 2015? I would seriously consider updating that to something a bit more recent.

Looking at Visual Studio, the installed version is 2.68.1. I think I should poke around to see where that resides in the file system.

Yeah, if you have a later version installed you should try updating the --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc= option to refer to a later version.

@phuzi I can't seem to find the newer version. Neither Windows Search nor google is being helpful. Can you tell me where I can download the latest version of that plugin?

You've already stated that VS states that 2.68.1 is being used so you might not need to update anything in the project/solution. It may just been the protoc command you're running that refers to the ancient version. Check the nuget packages folder to see if there is the latest version

Found it. For some reason, I thought there's no other version in that directly, but there is one. Update to the latest version, and it's fixed. Thanks a lot!

No problem. I'll add that as an answer.

"As far as I can tell, I need to manually generate the C# code using protoc" -- you shouldn't have to, no. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-9.0#add-a-proto-file-to-a-c-app

I might be wrong, but I thought that only works for .net core projects. This is a .net framework project, and that is not by choice, we have a hard dependency on a binary that is .net framework only.

Your protoc command appears to be using an ancient version of the csharp grpc plugin that was released way back in 2015! I would guarantee that the generated C# has come a long way since then.
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="C:\users\foo\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\0.5.0\tools\grpc_csharp_plugin.exe"
You've stated in the comments that the project/solution is using the latest version (currently 2.68.1). You should update the --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc= option to refer to the installed version so that the generated C# code is in-sync with the installed GRPC.Core package.
C:\users\foo\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\2.68.1 directory.
